# Zbar : startPreview failed in galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-camera, zbar

I have used [ZBAR library](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android) to scan bar code in my Application.

And I got this error log while opening camera on Samsung Galaxy S3 :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
at com.SGID.MainApp.ScanningFragment.engageCamera(ScanningFragment.java:184)
at com.SGID.MainApp.ScanningFragment.access$10(ScanningFragment.java:154)
at com.SGID.MainApp.ScanningFragment$4.run(ScanningFragment.java:111)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.SGID.MainApp/com.SGID.MainApp.AllTabsActivity}
: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.SGID.MainApp.ParametersFragment.onCreateView(ParametersFragment.java:78)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
... 11 more
```

**EDIT :** 
Getting error  at this line :

```
CameraPreview mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb,
                    autoFocusCB);
```

Can Anyone help me to resolve this error??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: As I understood I got NullPointerException. So of this params might be null. Check them in debug :getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB

Comment: I cant reproduce this error..Client faced this issue so I cant debug :(